# Extract hardcoded subtitles

Tags: dvd, video-subtitles, ocr

I wanted to know if there is a way to extract hardcoded subtitles via OCR, should I do some image processing after extracting the frames in order to use `tesseract` afterwards?

I have tried to extract frames from the video and remove everything that is not the color of the subtitles, but I got terrible results when using `tesseract` afterwards.

Is it possible to get decent results only using some workaround like this or should I rather train `tesseract` myself? It is easy to generate training data from random quotes added on random movie pictures with random fonts but it will require a lot of time to train it.

Comment: It may help to show us an image after the color is removed.